# Attaching the same message to several symbols

Tags: packages, message-coding

It is common in many packages, as well as system symbols, that the same message can be issued by several functions.  Here's an example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One mechanism that can be used for this is to define the message only once, and attach it to  the `General` symbol.  This is how the `infy` messages works as well.  `infy` can appear to come from any symbol:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When writing a custom package, it might not be the best idea to do this though because of the risk of message conflicts. Two packages might attach the same message identifier to `General`, so the one that's loaded last will overwrite the previous one.  In fact, looking at the some standard packages (e.g. CUDALink), they do not attach messages to `General` even when the same message can be issued by several functions.  Looking at the source code of the package, CUDALink uses a helper function to attach the same message text to several symbols in one go.

**The question:**  What is the best way to proceed when several functions need to be able to issue the same message, and indicate that it is coming from them?  What do you use in your own packages?

What's important for me is minimizing the risk of conflict with other packages and the simplicity of implementation.

Comment: Once I saw it done by cascading `$NewMessage` functions, but I can't remember where.  If I remember well, it wasn't too difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about doing something as simple as

```
sym1::msg = "I am feeling grumpy.";
sym2::msg = sym3::msg = sym1::msg;
```

Then

```
Do[With[{ff = f}, 
  Message[MessageName[ff, "msg"]]], {f, {sym1, sym2, sym3}}]
```

Outputs

```
sym1::msg: I am feeling grumpy.

sym2::msg: I am feeling grumpy.

sym3::msg: I am feeling grumpy.
```

Answer (score 9):

Messages defined for a symbol are stored in list of rules `Messages[sym]` similar to `DownValues`, `UpValues` etc. We can use this fact to create general message inheritance mechanism.

Let's start with defining custom message on our own `general` symbol:

```
ClearAll[general]
general::myMessage = "text of general myMessage"
```

As expected this message is stored in a list as a delayed rule:

```
Messages[general]
(* {HoldPattern[general::myMessage] :> "text of general myMessage"} *)
```

Now let's try to define a symbol which will inherit messages from our `general` symbol. First attempt would be:

```
ClearAll[testSym]
MessageName[testSym, name_] := MessageName[testSym, name]
(* During evaluation of In[4]:= Message::name: Message name testSym::name_ is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language. >>
$Failed *)
```

It fails since `MessageName` is protected from passing non-string as second argument. Also attempt of assigning anything else than explicit string fails:

```
testSym::myMessage := general::myMessage
(* During evaluation of In[6]:= MessageName::messg: testSym::myMessage cannot be set to general::myMessage. It must be set to a string. >>
$Failed *)
```

But nothing prevents us from adding hand crafted rule to `Messages` list:

```
AppendTo[Messages[testSym],
    HoldPattern[MessageName[testSym, name_]] :> MessageName[general, name]
]
(* {HoldPattern[testSym::name_] :> general::name} *)
```

There were no `Message::name` warnings since none of `MessageName` expressions was evaluated. The one on left hand side is wrapped in `HoldPattern` and the one on the right is protected from evaluation by `RuleDelayed`. They will be evaluated only when called:

```
MessageName[testSym, "myMessage"]
(* "text of general myMessage" *)

Message[testSym::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[9]:= testSym::myMessage: text of general myMessage *)
```

Problem arises when we want to call message from "real" `General` symbol on our inheriting symbol:

```
Message[testSym::argctu, testSym]
(* A lot of StringSplit::strse, StringJoin::string, StringForm::string errors *)
```

It fails since, where `Message` was expecting a string, it go `MessageName[general, argctu]`, which does not evaluate to a string. We can easily prevent such situations by adding a `Condition` to our "inheritance" rule, such that rule matches only when `MessageName[general, name]` evaluates to a string.

```
ClearAll[testSym]
AppendTo[Messages[testSym],
    HoldPattern[MessageName[testSym, name_]] :>
        MessageName[general, name] /; StringQ[MessageName[general, name]]
]
(* {HoldPattern[testSym::name_] :> general::name /; StringQ[general::name]} *)
```

Now everything works as expected. If message is not defined on `testSym`, but is defined on `general`, message from `general` is used:

```
Message[testSym::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[13]:= testSym::myMessage: text of general myMessage *)
```

If message is not defined neither on `testSym` nor on `general`, ordinary delegation to "real" `General` is used:

```
Message[testSym::argctu, testSym]
(* During evaluation of In[14]:= testSym::argctu: testSym called with 1 argument. >> *)
```

If we explicitly define a message on `testSym`, normal pattern specificity applies and message from `testSym` is used:

```
testSym::myMessage = "text of testSym myMessage";
Message[testSym::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[15]:= testSym::myMessage: text of testSym myMessage *)
```

## Usage in a package

```
BeginPackage["ToyPackage`"]

ToyFunc1::usage = ""
ToyFunc2::usage = ""
$ToyVariable::usage = ""
$ToyVariableWithMessages::usage = ""

Begin["`Private`"]
general::myMessage = "general myMessage"
general::myMessageWithArg = "general myMessageWithArg: `1`"
ToyFunc1::myMessage = "ToyFunc1 myMessage"
ToyFunc2::myMessageWithArg = "ToyFunc2 myMessageWithArg: `1`"
$ToyVariable = "$ToyVariable value"
$ToyVariableWithMessages = "$ToyVariableWithMessages value"

Function[
    sym
    ,
    Quiet[MessageName[sym, name_] =., Unset::norep];

    AppendTo[Messages[sym],
        HoldPattern[MessageName[sym, name_]] :>
            MessageName[general, name] /;
                StringQ[MessageName[general, name]]
    ]
    ,
    HoldFirst
] @@@
    (ToExpression[#, InputForm, Hold]&) /@
        DeleteCases[Names["ToyPackage`*"], "$ToyVariable"]

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

`ToyFunc1` inherits from `general` and overrides `myMessage`:

```
Message[ToyFunc1::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[1]:= ToyFunc1::myMessage: ToyFunc1 myMessage *)
Message[ToyFunc1::myMessageWithArg, "arg"]
(* During evaluation of In[2]:= ToyFunc1::myMessageWithArg: general myMessageWithArg: arg *)
Message[ToyFunc1::argctu, ToyFunc1]
(* During evaluation of In[3]:= ToyFunc1::argctu: ToyFunc1 called with 1 argument. >> *)
```

`ToyFunc2` inherits from `general` and overrides `myMessageWithArg`:

```
Message[ToyFunc2::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[4]:= ToyFunc2::myMessage: general myMessage *)
Message[ToyFunc2::myMessageWithArg, "arg"]
(* During evaluation of In[5]:= ToyFunc2::myMessageWithArg: ToyFunc2 myMessageWithArg: arg *)
Message[ToyFunc2::argctu, ToyFunc1]
(* During evaluation of In[6]:= ToyFunc2::argctu: ToyFunc1 called with 1 argument. >> *)
```

`$ToyVariable` was explicitly excluded from inheritance:

```
Message[$ToyVariable::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[7]:= $ToyVariable::myMessage: -- Message text not found -- *)
Message[$ToyVariable::myMessageWithArg, "arg"]
(* During evaluation of In[8]:= $ToyVariable::myMessageWithArg: -- Message text not found -- (arg) *)
Message[$ToyVariable::argctu, $ToyVariable]
(* During evaluation of In[9]:= $ToyVariable::argctu: $ToyVariable value called with 1 argument. >> *)
```

`$ToyVariableWithMessages` inherits from `general` and doesn't override anything:

```
Message[$ToyVariableWithMessages::myMessage]
(* During evaluation of In[10]:= $ToyVariableWithMessages::myMessage: general myMessage *)
Message[$ToyVariableWithMessages::myMessageWithArg, "arg"]
(* During evaluation of In[11]:= $ToyVariableWithMessages::myMessageWithArg: general myMessageWithArg: arg *)
Message[$ToyVariableWithMessages::argctu, $ToyVariableWithMessages]
(* During evaluation of In[12]:= $ToyVariableWithMessages::argctu: $ToyVariableWithMessages value called with 1 argument. >> *)
```

Answer (score 2):

`NDSolve` uses `` NDSolve`NDSolveMessage[] `` to do something like what @Sascha suggests in his answer. It creates (or loads) the messages on the fly, and defines them for the `*NDSolve*` functions that use them.  Writing such a function should not be hard, but I will show another approach prompted by [@belisarius's hint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20377/attaching-the-same-message-to-several-symbols/66383#comment62478_20377).

The main difference from `NDSolveMessage` is that it defines the message only for the specified symbol.
The function `myMessage[g::tag, args...]` works like `Message`, except that if the message `g::tag` is undefined, it it uses `$NewMessage` to look for a message `foo::tag` and defines `g::tag = foo::tag` (Sascha's method), if it finds one.
(One could add an argument `msghead` to specify which symbol's messages to search instead of a hard-coded `foo`.)

```
ClearAll[myMessage];
SetAttributes[myMessage, HoldFirst];
myMessage[m : MessageName[f_, name_], args___] := Block[{
   $NewMessage = Function[{symbol, tag},
     If[MemberQ[Keys@Messages[foo], 
       Verbatim[HoldPattern][HoldPattern@MessageName[foo, tag]]],
      MessageName[symbol, tag] = MessageName[foo, tag]
      ]]
   },
  Message[m, args]
  ];
```

Typical use-case:

```
Clear[foo];
foo::murf = "Try something other than ``.";

myMessage[myFunc::murf, 2]
```

> myFunc::murf: Try something other than 2.

```
myMessage[myFunc::undefined, 2]
```

The behavior on undefined messages is the same as `Message`

> myFunc::undefined: -- Message text not found -- (2)

```
Message[myFunc::undefined, 2]
```

> myFunc::undefined: -- Message text not found -- (2)

```
Messages[myFunc]
(*  {HoldPattern[myFunc::murf] :> "Try something other than ``."}  *)
```

---

Addendum: An example of the `` NDSolve`NDSolveMessage `` behavior.
`NDSolveMessage` defines the message for each relevant function,
including `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions ``, `` NDSolve`Iterate ``, etc. It defines a message only for the functions that use it (for `` NDSolve`Iterate `` but not for `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions `` or vice versa and so forth), but it defines the message for all the selected functions at once.
In the code for `` NDSolve`NDSolveMessage `` there must be a database of messages and head to attach them to. I haven't been able to find it, though.
Some code for `` NDSolve`* `` is exposed and can be inspected with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``. For instance, the `InitializeMethod[]` of `` NDSolve`ExplicitRungeKutta `` shows several uses of `NDSolveMessage`; however no code for `NDSolveMessage` itself is exposed.

[image]